# How to share Flash Screen (multiuser whiteboard)

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

How can I make a Flash Application that can be shared? Shared in the sense of like a paint box. If someone is painting there then the painting must be shown to all users. This means each user can write and edit in the paint box at the same time...

Regards,

Emraan Khalil

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a whiteboard. I'm not sure how you could push updates to all users but the following two links might help for managing users and getting data. http://library.creativecow.net/articles/brimelow_lee/php_mysql.php
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

unless you are specifically trying to learn how to create the entire system from scratch, you probably want to use an existing framework or server product. for example, here's a shared mouse pointer application for union platform (which is free for 1000 simultaneous connections):

http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=997

to turn that application into a drawing board, simply add line drawing to the multiuser mouse movements.

depending on what you are building, you might also want to consider a javascript implementation. here's the source for a multiuser paint app for javascript:

http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=2762

there are lots of other server options out there...try searching for flash socket server or flash multiuser server.